# how to scroll to bottom in Avaloniaui

Tags: wpf, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a textbox wrapped by a scrollviewer.
Is there a way to automatically scroll down to the bottom when the text of the textbox changes? I hope don't violate the mvvm rules.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="LogSV" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBox x:Name="LogText" Text="{Binding Log}" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You can do this in the background with the TextChanged event. It does not violate MVVM.

Comment: There is no TextChanged event in Avalonia...

Comment: Don't you use this? https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit

Comment: No, the framework I use is this.
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the `TextBox` and change the scroll if the property name is `Text`.

```
private readonly ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;

public UserControl()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.FindControl<TextBox>("LogText").PropertyChanged += TextBoxPropertyChanged;
   _scrollViewer = this.FindControl<ScrollViewer>("LogSV");
}

private void TextBoxPropertyChanged(object? sender, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Property.Name == "Text")
   {
      _scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
   }
}
```